# GIMP: Text Tool only selects the letters themselves, not the spaces inbetween them

Tags: gimp

This is a really something that's gotten under my skin. Whenever I try and select a line of text, it goes to make a box around the nearby letter. When I try to add a space in between the letters, it instead replaces the letter. How do I switch back to selecting the spaces inbetween the letters, rather than the letters themselves?

Comment: The answer I can think of is "click where you want the text cursor to be, adjust with cursor keys if necessary/faster". Also, GIMP doesn't seem to behave any different than a text editor or e.g. the text entry I'm using for this comment, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: It sounds like the kerning has bee adjusted, and what you are trying to select is not actually spaces.  How about a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not make any sense - except if you have met the following GIMP's property (it was the same in old text editing software):

You try to click the nearly nonexistent free room between the characters to insert some text. You type new text. It replaces the old writing, but you wanted to insert some characters without removing anything.

The solution: Hit Insert key before typing the text. That toggles between text inserting and replacing modes. Narrow cursor means inserting and a box around a character means replacing that character.

Answer (score 0):

The selection in the text tool only applies to characters. You can select space between characters if it corresponds a "space" character (regular space (ASCII 32/0x20), or the various varieties of narrow, wide, breaking, etc... spaces). Otherwise blank pixels between characters are just part of the definition of the glyphs of the previous/next character and their spacing/kerning. All text editors work that way...

Gimp supports the [exotic space characters](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) if the font used supports it. And in particular if you add a zero-width space (U+200B) you can select it. These characters are usually hard to enter with keyboard alone, but can be copy-pasted from other documents (such as the page linked above).

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+U 200B. The key combo gives you an underlined u to indicate you have entered Unicode mode, then you let go and just enter the rest of the characters.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Learn something everyday :)

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing insert key. You might have pressed it by mistake and that causes the effect you mentioned in any typing interface.